# the usage of a comparative form "at a position...than at a position "

Tags: comparison

[image]

I am trying to describe the color of the portion A in the picture shown above.
My examples are as follows:

> 1. In the bar, the color of the portion A is darker at a position
>      closer to the center than at a position closer to the right end.
> 2. In the bar, the color of the portion A is darker as the portion A is
>      closer to the center of the bar than to the right end of the bar.

I am unsure whether my examples are correct because when I googled the expression "at a position...than at a position", I found only a few results.  Could you advise me on my examples?

Comment: "**In the bar, the color of the potion A is *darker towards the center* and *brighter towards the right end***" is a good replacement.

Comment: I think it would be necessary to know if portion A were fixed in the bar, or moved within it. Both examples seem to suggest portion A is not fixed.

Comment: The portion A is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the supplied information,  example 1:

> In the bar, the color of the portion A is darker at a position closer to the center than at a position closer to the right end.

is closer to being correct. However, because **position A** is fixed in the bar, the prepositional phrase "at a position" is irrelevant, and possibly confusing. So

> In the bar, the color of the portion A is darker  closer to the center than  closer to the right end.

supplies the information without ambiguity.  SovereignSun's suggestion in comments is good.

Example 2:

> In the bar, the color of the portion A is darker as the portion A is closer to the center of the bar than to the right end of the bar.

suggests a **cause and effect** [cause and effect](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cause--and--effect)  relationship with the position of **portion A** relative to the bar center (this possibly can be read to suggest that moving **portion A** toward the bar center will cause the colors to become darker).
I would not use example 2 as a model.
I hope this helps. If it does not, please post any concerns in comments.